# How to download files into download folder in cordova

Tags: cordova, download, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on VS2015 Apache cordova app and i want to save files from remote server into download folder . I 'v added file and file transfer plugins into my project . here is my code :

```
$("#SaveFiles").click(function () {
var _fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();                     
var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "/Download-Button1.png";
 var uri = encodeURI("http://www.techaudible.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Download-Button1.png");
        _fileTransfer.download(
     uri,
     filePath,
     function (entry) {
         alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
     },
     function (error) {
         alert(error);
         alert("download error source " + error.source);
         alert("download error target " + error.target);
         alert("upload error code" + error.code);
     }
 );
});
```

When i fire this button i get this alert
[image]

but i didn't get it in the path . i am not sure it is successfully downloaded but i want to download it into download file in the mobile device , i tried that
as declared in
[How do you download a file to Android's Downloads folder using Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574051/how-do-you-download-a-file-to-androids-downloads-using-phonegap)

but "LocalFileSystem" didn't defined in my code . i don't sure if i should import another plugin .
Any advice . Thank you .

Comment: hmm try with window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT